# Open file dialog in power apps, is that possible?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-modeldriven

I want to allow the user to click a button and open File Explorer, select an Excel File and open it in a Gallery.
Is there anyway to do that in PowerApps?

The Excel Files always have 6 columns. I update the data and it is exported as excel again.

Comment: Are you using a model-driven app

Comment: @SaqibVaid yes a model-driven app. Sorry too late answer, I didn't get a notification.